# php/ajax how can I replace a specific button with text when number of buttons change?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have already figured out how to replace a button with jquery and ajax like this:

```
$("#addButton").hide();
$('.form').show();
```

But on another page I display multiple submit buttons that each submit different data to a database, and I don't know how to keep track of which button is which so that when clicked only that button disappears?

The page is created dynamically based on a search result so I have a different amount of buttons each time. I tried passing a variable for the name of an element but did not know how to then use that variable in the jquery call?

If you all have any ideas about how I can go about accomplishing this, I would appreciate it.

Update:

Here is the form being created that displays the search results and a form to click a button to send a friend request.

```
for($i = 0; $i<$numF;$i++){
                        $row = $resultF->fetch_assoc();
                        $friendName = $row['userName'];
                        $friendID = $row['userID'];

                        print "  
                                    <p> $friendName </p>
                                    <form method = \"post\" action = \"\" onsubmit =  \" return addFriend('$userID','$user','$friendName', '$friendID')\" >
                                         <input type = \"submit\" value = \"Send friend Request\" />    
                                    </form>


                                <hr>
                        ";

                    }
```

Also here is the function being called:

```
function addFriend(userID,user,friendName, friendID)
    {
        //run ajax
        var ajaxSettings = {
            type: "GET",
            url: "friendRequest.php",
            data: "uID="+userID+"&uName="+user+"&fName="+friendName+"&fID="+friendID,
            error: function(xhr, status, error) { alert("error: " + error); } };            

            $.ajax(ajaxSettings);

        return false;
     }
```

Comment: Including your html and more of your js would probably be helpful.  I also don't see any sign of AJAX or php, though both are mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to which button was clicked using `this`:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $(this).hide()
}
```

Will hide the clicked button. Other than that, I don't know how to help you because you didn't supply enough information.

Comment: I noticed I was vague thanks to James, so I added some more information. Thanks!

Comment: where would I pit that jquery string?